# code in emacs loses format

Tags: emacs, clipboard, copy-paste

When I write a piece of code, then open it with visual studio or sublime text 3. The code will lose the original format.
Also, when I copy formatted from other sources and paste into emacs, the format will be broken. Same thing happens when paste code to other sources from emacs.
How to solve it?

Comment: Not enough info to understand what you mean by "loses format," but a probable suspect is tab characters. Check that you have matching definitions of tab characters on the source and target side - whether tab characters are preserved, and if not, how many spaces replace a tab character.

Comment: What @YuriSteinschreiber said. And show or describe what you mean by "broken format", in both directions. Provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the effect, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's going on definitively without a concrete example, but it sounds like there could be several factors at play.

In this use case, Emacs is just an editor manipulating text-based files. 
As far as source code being displayed differently in your buffers as compared to other editors and IDEs for the same text-content: that formatting is mostly, depending on the file, controlled by a major and one or more minor modes.

You can see the current modes by entering `C-h m`. These modes have variables you can customize, which control, as one example, indentation levels. It's possible your config settings aren't the same as those used by other editors.

If that's the case, when you enter, say, a newline, Emacs could be changing the whitespace of enclosing code blocks on the fly. This would be more pronounced if your Emacs were maybe converting spaces to tabs, or vice-versa. You can get rid of tabs with `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`, which should help with interop as most editors generally convert tab presses to spaces.